# conhost.exe seemingly leaking memory

Tags: .net, windows, memory-leaks, console

I have a .NET Framework ASP.NET application running in IIS. The application launches a long-lived sub-process but is otherwise unremarkable (just one endpoint which effectively proxies requests to the sub-process).

While the system is serving requests, the memory usage for conhost.exe on the machine steadily rises (~linear growth); after about a day it will be consuming .5-1 GB. Every 29 hours, the IIS application pool automatically recycles itself; at this point the conhost usage drops back to zero but then starts steadily growing again.

What could cause conhost to use this much memory?

UPDATE:

I saw that the settings for `Console.BufferWidth` and `Console.BufferHeight` can lead to more memory usage in conhost.exe. Therefore, I added logging for these values. However, my app shows a constant small buffer width and height.

UPDATE:

Per @simon-mourier's comment we pulled the dlls attached to the conhost process. All are in System32. The list is: conhost, ntdll, kernel32, kernelbase, msvcrt, Conhostv2, combase, ucrtbase, RPCRT4, bcryptPrimitives, GDI32, gdi32full, USER32, win32u, IMM32, OLEAUT32, msvcp_win, PROPSYS, sechost, shcore, SHELL32, cfgmgr32, windows.storage, powerprof, advapi32, shlwapi, kernel.appcore, and profapi.

UPDATE:

Seems similar to (if not the same as) [ASP.NET Core ILogger Memory Leak on Windows 10 (1607) / Windows Server 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63063591/asp-net-core-ilogger-memory-leak-on-windows-10-1607-windows-server-2016) . Unfortunately that also lacks answers.

Comment: Does your ASP.NET application create any subprocesses (Typically with `Process.Start()` but there are other ways)?  Would the executables it is spawning as subprocesses happen to be console applications?

Comment: @BenVoigt yes the subprocess spawns is a console application.

Comment: @BenVoigt any theory as to why that would cause conhost.exe to leak? The subprocess itself does not seem to be leaking memory.

Comment: You can check the dll attached to this conhost.exe process (using Process Explorer tool from sysinternals for example) see if anything looks suspicious (3rd party dll, etc.)

Comment: @SimonMourier I was able to pull the list and I posted it in the question. Everything was from System32. Does anything stand out to you?

Comment: If everything is Microsoft and in system32, that looks normal

Comment: @Charlieface would XmlSerializer cause high memory usage in conhost.exe? That's a native executable.

Comment: There might be an injected DLL which is leaking. Again, a profiler might help

Comment: @ChaseMedallion based on the other answer, OS version seems to be significant. What version are *you* running?

Comment: @Kit I'm running Windows Server 2016

Comment: @ChaseMedallion Sorry for the late reply, I posted an answer how to fix the issue I had: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68577179/779506 OS version is indeed relevant, thus if your issue is only happening on Server 2016 this might be related.

Comment: @sky thanks so much I will give this a try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a Windows OS bug. We contacted Microsoft support about the issue and received a patch (likely the same patch mentioned by @sky in stackoverflow.com/a/68577179/779506).